# Walls: Protect from scratches, dents, dirt, etc

Tags: drywall, repair, walls, painting

I have a contractor fixing/repainting my ceilings and doing repair work around my place. I want to protect the walls, not only from dirt, but scratches, dents, etc. if the contractor's ladder etc rubs the wall.

Are there any thicker/durable wall protectors besides the plastic sheeting?  What other materials are there in the business?

[image]

Comment: The plastic sheeting is mainly to keep paint off of things.  Most contractors are responsible for any damage they cause and should repair it to the same as it was before work.  Pictures before and after the work might come in handy.

Comment: I suggest you protect your walls by choosing your workers carefully, in other words, by watching them as they work on another project to see if they are meticulous by nature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are various paper products more typically used for floor protection - Builders kraft paper, red rosin paper, on up to the heavy-duty stuff like ramboard (which is a specific brand that I'm not endorsing, just using as a common example.)

These products typically come about 3 feet wide and in long rolls. I would compare the ramboard and competitors to a long sheet of cereal box cardboard, as something you may be familiar with, to get a sense of it before you find some at a store.

**However** - this should really be on the contractor - to do no damage, or to protect from doing damage, or to repair any damage done.

Comment: so kraft paper, red rosin ,  and then ramboard, anything else in between? We are also getting good contractor, thanks

Comment: Mostly various thicknesses of the thicker cardboard-ish stuff.